# Custom code generation for JPA entities from database

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I'm here asking for a simple way to add some custom code in the JPA Entity generated by Eclipse from database.

Basically what I want to achieve is to add public String properties containing the names of the entity properties, and use them when I need to provide "property name" as String and be sure that there won't be runtime access errors.

Something like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="clients")
@NamedQuery(name="ClientModel.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM ClientModel c")
public class ClientModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_client")
    private long idClient;

    public String name;

    public ClienteModel() {
    }

    public long getIdClient() {
        return this.idClient;
    }

    public void setIdClient(long idClient) {
        this.idClient = idClient;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //CUSTOM CODE
    public static final String idClientProperty = "idClient";
    public static final String nameProperty = "name";
}
```

So i could use property name like

```
ClientModel.nameProperty
```

and be compile-time safe of his existence and in case of names refactoring after a further entity generation.

I'm aware of the existence of Telosys Tools & co., but I hoped there could be something simplier/faster (like a custom class provided as plugin in WSDL_to_entity generation with JAXB)

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end I've used Telosys Tools, even if I didn't want to add another tool to my project,
Is kinda easy to set up, just read here
https://sites.google.com/site/telosystools/getting-started/21-configure-a-project

In my specific case i've added to the template "JPA_bean_with_links" this code during getters creation

```
#if ( $field.getter )    public static String ${field.getter}Property() {
        return "$field.name";
    }
#end
```